# Не могу получить нужные данные по запросу Tinkoff Invest API

Tags: python, python-openai

Сейчас работаю над созданием торгового робота, и мне нужно собрать исторические данные. Но я получаю по многим бумагам не все данные. К примеру, если я запрашиваю данные с 28 января 2022 года по 28 января 2024 года с таймфреймом в час, по акциям Тинькофф я получаю только данные до 2 ноября 2023 года, по акциям Сбер, Лукойл я вообще ничего не получаю. Единственная акция по которой я получаю данные за весь временной интервал, это X5 Retail Group.
Я уверен, что запрос исторических свеч написал правильно, так-как проверял с несколькими разными промежутками на разных таймфремах и бумагах.
Это проблема самого API или текущей обстановки на фондовом рынке?

Comment: Это всё российские акции или GDR, торговавшиеся на зарубежных биржах? Так то да, изучайте обстановку, с зарубежными акциями и с GDR российских акций всё довольно печально. По чисто российским акциям, обращающимся на Московской бирже, всё должно быть нормально по идее. Хотя Лукойл вроде нигде не блокировали, насколько я помню, это вот странно.